# Fire-base push notification starts the app when message received even whiteout clicking the message

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Push notification for Android App, starts the app when received the message while App is not running (killed), even without clicking at the notification. Does any one knows if this is the default Android behavior or there is some settings I need to change?

Comment: That depends on the type of message you send. Notification-only messages will be handled by the system if the app is not active. But data messages will always be delivered to your app's `onMessageReceived` handler.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, even if I don't add any data (Notification only), it will start my app, is that default behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure. It really depends on what "start my app" means. What do you send, and what code in your app do you see being triggered?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, by "start my app" I mean when the app is Neither on Background nor Foreground, when the notification received, it will open up the app (start), without clicking on notification, but when the app is either on Background or Foreground nothing happens until you touch (click) the notification.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not clear on what you mean by *open up the app (start)*.

Here is what I see when a notification-only message is sent to an app that is not in memory (version 11.8.0):

- An instance of the app is created. This occurs even when the app does not define a service that extends [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest).
- If the app *does* define a `FirebaseMessagingService`, the service is created and destroyed. `onMessageReceived()` is not called.
- In both cases, all processing occurs in the background; no activity is started until the user taps on the notification.
- These observations are based on log messages output from my messaging service and [Application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) instance.

While the descriptions in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages), such as *FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app*, correctly indicate that the handling of the message is done "by the system", they don't mention that creation of an app instance is a side effect of that processing.

Comment: I extended FireBaseMessagingService, and onMessageReceived gets called every time, I think that's the purpose. by Open up the app (start) I mean when the app is Not active, it opens the app WITHOUT tapping

Comment: Can you update your post to include the message you are sending. For a non-foreground app, `onMessageReceived()` should only be called if there are data fields.